# Programmatically set google map fragment visibility (API2)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, visibility

xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

In regular fragment it goes like this:

```
  mFragment = (mFragment) (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mFragment));
  mFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

In Google map fragment:

```
  mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment)).getMap();
```

But how can I set map fragment visibility progrematically?

Can't do it like others fragment.

Comment: You can try to cast `mMap` to `Fragment` and execute same `getView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`, because `SupportMapFragment` is still a fragment.

Comment: Cannot cast from GoogleMap to Fragment

Comment: Did you try to use `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransacton().hide(mMap).commit()` or `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransacton().detach(mMap).commit()`?

Comment: Tried. But didn't work. As long as map declared like this: `private GoogleMap mMap;` I'm getting: "The method hide/detach(Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (GoogleMap)"

Comment: Sory my mistake, try this one:`getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransacton().hide(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment)).commit()` or `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment).getView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Simple as this:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
private SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;

mMapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment));
mMap = mMapFragment.getMap();

mMapFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: This helped me figure out how to programmatically change the height of the support map fragment. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21469345/how-do-you-programmatically-change-the-width-height-of-google-maps-v2-support/21483722#21483722

Comment: If the map is in a ScrollView, when I hide my scrollview the map doesn't hide. If I hide the map before the Scrollview it still doesn't hide. I had to hide the map, wait 1 milisecond, and then hide the scrollview using Timer.

Answer (score 23):

You can do:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(mFragment).commit();
```

to show it:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show(mFragment).commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Both the answer By `@David` and `@ferdy182` are right but they don't told the context.

if you hide/show fragment Programmatically then use `@ferdy182` and if you want to hide/show fragment which is in xml. you should follow `@David`

Let me explain

If you are having a single frameLayout in xml and you want to replace the other fragment in that particular one after another. use this code to add all fragment . they will be place on one another.

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, frag[i])
            //.addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
        }// add all these fragment and put them on each other then
```

hide all other fragment except which you want to show.

```
for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(frag[j]).commit();
        }
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show(frag[0]).commit();
```

**Benefit**
  These fragment work like form in c#. Forum.show and forum.hide(); . Where there current state remain their. these fragment don't call again and again. A [**problem here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24779275/how-to-show-hide-a-fragment/24779555?noredirect=1#comment38460886_24779555) i solve it using this technique. 
2nd Method

when you are having multiple frameLayout or fragment in xml . you can hide that particular by getting its id.

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
private SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;

mMapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment));
mMap = mMapFragment.getMap();

mMapFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

**Codes**

// to show fragment when it is hidden

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction()
          .show(fragment1)
          .commit();
```

// to hide fragment

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction()
          .hide(fragment1)
          .commit();
```

Comment: You should not hide it by changing its visibility. hide and show work also with fragments defined in xml, you only have to do a findFragmentById to pass the fragment instance to the fragment transaction

Answer (score 0):

Only that works for me :

```
View fragmentMap = layout.findViewById(R.id.map_fragment_container_id);
fragmentMap.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a `SupportMapFragment` in xml, there could be another approach in which we can define container for `SupportMapFragment` in xml and then load map from class.

In XML, let say container is `FrameLayout`-

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mapContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

In my java class which is a `Fragment`, I have created two methods to show and hide map. I used detach and it depends on need. We can also use hide instead of detach.

```
   private void showMap() {
   mMapContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   mSupportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
   getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                         .replace(R.id.mapContainer, mSupportMapFragment).commit();
   }

    private void hideMap() {
        mMapContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (mSupportMapFragment != null) {
            getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                 .detach(mSupportMapFragment).commit();
        }
    }
```