# How to hide GoogleMaps object

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I have a GoogleMaps object and I want to hide it when the phone is not connected to the internet.
GoogleMaps V2

Comment: what is your question ? have you tried anything ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Map api 2 how to show/hide GoogleMap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16936624/google-map-api-2-how-to-show-hide-googlemap)

Comment: I've tried the first solution from this question but Android Studio says: expected Fragment found com.....GoogleMap

Answer (score 0):

I've found a possible solution, I put it in a liearlayout then I can hide this layout:

```
mLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```