# How do you programmatically change the width & height of Google Maps v2 (support Fragment)?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-maps-v2

How do you programatically change the width and height of a com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment? I'd imagine you might be able to wrap it in a viewgroup with match_parent, but I'm hoping not to nest if I don't have to (honestly not even sure it works).

```
 <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/storefront_map"
                    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    />
```

To give context, I'd like to expand the map from one height to another on map click.

```
mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
       expandMap(); // not sure how to do this programatically.
    }
});
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I figured it out largely with the help of [Programmatically set google map fragment visibility (API2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13833709/programmatically-set-google-map-fragment-visibility-api2?rq=1).

```
mMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) (getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.storefront_map));
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mMapFragment.getView().getLayoutParams();
params.height = 900;
mMapFragment.getView().setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 4):

this is an example using `onConfigurationChanged()` method :

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    findViewById(R.id.storefront_map).getLayoutParams().width = 400;
}
```

Comment: I updated my question to give better context of what I want to do.

Answer (score 3):

Fastest (with less code lines) way i found:

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams parms = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) rlLocation.getLayoutParams();
    parms.bottomMargin = 100;
    parms.topMargin = 100;
```

Comment: You normally would want to resize the map to accommodate another element. If the element has a fixed size, like it was in my case, setting a margin to the size of the inserted element is preferable. Good tip, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should not fix height of a map... set it according to screen height & width.

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mMapFragment.getView().getLayoutParams();
        params.height = height/2;
        mMapFragment.getView().setLayoutParams(params);
```