# How to Hide Map Fragment - Android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-fragmentactivity, mapfragment

Using below code to `show` and `hide` **MapFragment**, and it works just well:

```
public class MapFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {
...........
mMapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
googleMap = mMapFragment.getMap();  
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
.....
if(isChecked)
  {                                 
        mMapFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                                     
  }
  else 
  {
        mMapFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
```

but whenever i am using it with `Animation`, Map never hides, it always `visible`, whereas animation works for me;

```
if(isChecked)
    {               
        mMapFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mMapFragment.getView().startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MapFragmentActivity.this,
         R.anim.slide_up));
    }
    else 
    {
        mMapFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mMapFragment.getView().startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MapFragmentActivity.this,
         R.anim.slide_down));
    }
```

Comment: Let me know if my answer solved your problem otherwise I'll update it... but you must accept any answer as a correct! :)

Comment: Check my answer, it might help - http://stackoverflow.com/a/43299111/1380032

Comment: Have you solved this? In order to help other people if this helped you feel free to upvote and mark this as a correct answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 11):

You can try this

```
      private GoogleMap mMap;
    private SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;

if(isCheked) {
       mMapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment));
    mMap = mMapFragment.getMap();
    
    mMapFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.Visible);
 
}
else {
   mMapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment));
    mMap = mMapFragment.getMap();
    
    mMapFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}
```

Or the easy way is doing :

```
    if(isCheked) {
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show(mFragment).commit();
               
        }
        else {
          getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(mFragment).commit();
        }
```

Try this out and let me know if it works.

Here's a snippet of the first method in Kotlin...

```
val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment?
mapFragment?.view?.visibility = View.GONE
```

Answer (score 5):

Fragments can be show/hide using transactions.

```
try {
        FragmentTransaction ft = .getFragmentManager ().beginTransaction ();
        ft.hide (mMapFragment);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace ();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The only way works for me :

```
View fragmentMap = layout.findViewById(R.id.map_fragment_container_id);
fragmentMap.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap the map fragment within a `FrameLayout`

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/mapLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/theMap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
</FrameLayout>
```

and then call the animation on the FrameLayout

```
int valueInPixels = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.task_list_map_height);
FrameLayout mapLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.mapLayout);
mapLayout.animate().translationY(-valueInPixels).setDuration(600);
```